# Hash lookup with an array of keys?

Tags: perl

I'd like to see if a hash contains any of a list of keys. Currently I have:

```
if (grep {$me_hash{$_}} @me_list){
    ...
```

but I figure it's inefficient because it doesn't quit on the first match. Is there a better, more idiomatic way to do it?

kthxbi

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`List::MoreUtils`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aMoreUtils)'s `any`

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(any);
if (any { $me_hash{$_} } @me_list) {
```

Which presumably short circuits on the first match. This function is rather simple, looking like this:

```
sub any (&@) {
    my $f = shift;
    foreach ( @_ ) {
        return YES if $f->();
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Where `YES` and `NO` are defined as

```
use constant YES => ! 0;
use constant NO  => ! 1;
```

Meaning you can swing your own version of this with something like

```
sub is_in {
    my ($href, @list) = @_;
    for (@list) {
        return 1 if $href->{$_};
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the statement you are using `$me_hash{$_}` can return false for values you might not consider false, such as the empty string, or zero `0`.

Comment: Note that all of `@me_list` is placed on the stack, but this should be very fast as it does not involve copying more than pointers.

Answer (score 1):

`List::Util` unlike `List::MoreUtils` is core module,

```
use List::Util qw(first);
if (defined first {$me_hash{$_}} @me_list) { .. }
```

and if you don't want to use any of external modules,

```
my $any = sub{ $me_hash{$_} and return 1 for @_; 0 }->(@me_list);
if ($any) { .. }
```